# Conquest PACS with postgres

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have a Conquest PACS I would like to use a pSQL database.

But when I query my PACS, I keep getting a `DBerror`.

As far as I can see in the logs, the PACS never queries the database.

My `dicom.ini` file looks like this:

```
# Network configuration: server name and TCP/IP port#                                                                          
MyACRNema                = PACS365                    
TCPPort                  = 104                    

# Reference to other files: known dicom servers; database layout; sops                                                         
ACRNemaMap               = /var/services/web/vpm/conf/acrnema.map
kFactorFile              = dicom.sql                    
SOPClassList             = dgatesop.lst                    
                                                                                # Host for postgres or mysql only, name, username and password for database                                                    
SQLHost                  = localhost                    
SQLServer                = conquest                    
Username                 = pacs                    
Password                 = pacs                    
PostGres                 = 1                    
MySQL                    = 0                    
SQLite                   = 0                    
                                                                                UseEscapeStringConstants = 1                    
DoubleBackSlashToDB      = 1                    
#IndexDBF                = 1                    
#PackDBF                 = 0                    
#LongQueryDBF            = 1000
```

Can anybody see what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You verified that the postgres installation was correct?

```
$ su - postgres
postgres = # set schema 'conquest';
postgres = # SELECT * from conquest.DICOMPatients;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Bond I'm work with Conquest Dicom Server and I'm sure my answer can clarify if the database is installed correctly. I know well this tool and I know that the issue has to do with access to the database. Discard up to find a problem is regarded as "good practice", which was not the problem in my answer.